# Add new item on top in custom adapter

Tags: android

I am not able to Add new item on top in custom adapter in Android. Post `CommentPageActivity` Class and `MyAdapter` Class for better understanding.

`CommentPageActivity` class populate `ListView` and on `onclick` action, we are calling `MyAdapter`

```
package com.sk.comment;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.sk.bhangarwaala.R;
import com.sk.variable.Globals;
import com.sk.variable.Variable;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CommentPageActivity extends Activity {
    MyAdapter listAdapter;
    ListView commentPageLvCommentsList;
    TextView commentPageTvSkid,commentPageTvLoader;
    EditText commentPageEtEnterComments;
    LinearLayout commentPageLlCommentsContainer;
    Button commentPageBtSubmit;
    List<CommentsFeedObj> data;
    String key,json;
    boolean isTaskCompleted,isError;
    LoadComments task= new LoadComments();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment_page);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_red)));
        // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        key=getIntent().getExtras().getString("skid");
        System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.onCreate() | key | "+key);

        data = new ArrayList<CommentsFeedObj>();

         Display d = ((Activity) this).getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay();
            int h = d.getHeight();
            int w = d.getWidth();

        System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.onCreate()|h|"+h+" |w|"+w); 

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.onCreate() |height| "+height);
        if(w>h){
            height=height*65/100;   
        }else{
            height=height*75/100;
        }

        System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.onCreate() |height| "+height);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);

        commentPageLlCommentsContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.commentPageLlCommentsContainer);
        commentPageLlCommentsContainer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        commentPageTvSkid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentPageTvSkid);
        commentPageTvSkid.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        commentPageEtEnterComments = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.commentPageEtEnterComments);
        System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.onCreate() width | | "+width);
        System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.onCreate() | 80/width*100 | "+width*80/100);
        commentPageEtEnterComments.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width*80/100, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        commentPageLvCommentsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.commentPageLvCommentsList);
        commentPageTvLoader=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentPageTvLoader);

        initLoadComments();

        commentPageBtSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.commentPageBtSubmit);
        //commentPageBtSubmit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_email_send);
        commentPageBtSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                performAddCommentsOperation();
            }
        });

    }

    void initLoadComments(){
        task.execute();
    }

    void loadCommentsView(){
        try {
            if(error)){
                CommentsFeedObj obj = new CommentsFeedObj();
                obj.setUserProfileImg("");
                obj.setUserName("");
                obj.setUserMsg("");
                obj.setTimestamp("");
                obj.setSkid(key);
                obj.setResponseStatus("error");
                data.add(obj);
            }else{
                parseJson(new JSONObject(json));    
            }

            listAdapter= new MyAdapter(this, data);
            commentPageLvCommentsList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    void parseJson(JSONObject response){
        System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.parseJson()");
        try {

            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");
            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                CommentsFeedObj obj = new CommentsFeedObj();
                obj.setUserProfileImg(feedObj.getString("userProfileImg"));
                obj.setUserName(feedObj.getString("userName"));
                obj.setUserMsg(feedObj.getString("userMsg"));
                obj.setTimestamp(feedObj.getString("timestamp"));
                obj.setSkid(feedObj.getString("skid"));
                obj.setLogonUserId(feedObj.getString("logonUserId"));
                obj.setLogonUserName(feedObj.getString("logonUserName"));
                obj.setLogonUserMobileNumber(feedObj.getString("logonUserMobileNumber"));
                obj.setUserLocation(feedObj.getString("userLocation"));
                obj.setTs_long(Long.parseLong(feedObj.getString("ts_long")));
                obj.setResponseStatus("success");
                data.add(obj);
            }
            System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.parseJson() | "+data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute(){
              super.onPreExecute();
              commentPageTvLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              commentPageTvLoader.setText("Loading...");      
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                int i=0;
                while(true){
                  i=i+1;
                  if(i==4){json=(Globals._N_LOADING_ERROR_COMMENTS); break;}

                  if(isTaskCompleted && (json==null || json.length()<1)){
                   task.execute(Variable.WS_URL_LOAD_COMMENTS);
                   isTaskCompleted=false;
                  }else if(isTaskCompleted&& (json!=null || json.length()>0))
                  {/*prgDialog.dismiss();*/break;}  

                  Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                      public void run() {  
                      } 
                  }, 200);
              }// while

            loadCommentsView();
            commentPageTvLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

          } 

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.LoadComments.doInBackground()");

            StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer("");
            List<NameValuePair> nameVauePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            InputStream is=null;

            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("skid", key));

            try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Variable.WS_URL_LOAD_COMMENTS);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameVauePairs));
            HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            StatusLine statusLine= response1.getStatusLine();
            System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.LoadComments.doInBackground() | statusLine | "+statusLine);

            {
              HttpEntity entity =response1.getEntity();
              is=entity.getContent();
              InputStreamReader in =new InputStreamReader(is);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
              String info="";
              String nl=System.getProperty("line.separator");

              while((info=br.readLine())!=null){
                  response.append(info.toString()+nl);
              }
              System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.LoadComments.doInBackground() | response.toString() | "+response.toString());
              json=response.toString();
                isTaskCompleted=true;
                isError=false;
              br.close();   
            }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                isTaskCompleted=true;
                isError=true;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                isTaskCompleted=true;
                isError=true;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                isTaskCompleted=true;
                isError=true;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }// doBackGroud
      }// SaveComment

    void performAddCommentsOperation(){
        System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.performAddCommentsOperation()");

        String msg=commentPageEtEnterComments.getText()+"".trim();
        String logonUserName=Globals.getInstance().getLogonUserName();
        String logonUserMobileNumber=Globals.getInstance().getLogonUserMobileNumber();
        String logonUserId=Globals.getInstance().getLogonUserId();

        if(msg==null || msg.length()<1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter comments", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            commentPageEtEnterComments.setText("");
            return;
        }
        commentPageEtEnterComments.setText("");

        if(logonUserName!=null && logonUserName.trim().length()>0){

        }else{
            logonUserName="unknown";
        }

        if(msg!=null && msg.trim().length()>0){

        }else{
            msg="nice shop";
        }

        CommentsFeedObj obj = new CommentsFeedObj();
        obj.setUserProfileImg("");
        obj.setUserName(logonUserName);
        obj.setUserMsg(msg);
        obj.setTimestamp(""+new Date());
        obj.setSkid(key);
        obj.setLogonUserId(logonUserId);
        obj.setLogonUserName(logonUserName);
        obj.setLogonUserMobileNumber(logonUserMobileNumber);
        obj.setUserLocation("");
        obj.setTs_long(System.currentTimeMillis());
        data.add(obj);

        listAdapter= new MyAdapter(this, data);
        //commentPageLvCommentsList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        performSaveCommentOperation(obj);

    }

    void performSaveCommentOperation(CommentsFeedObj obj){
        new SaveComment().execute(obj);
    }
    private class SaveComment extends AsyncTask<CommentsFeedObj, Void, String>{

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute(){
              super.onPreExecute();
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result){
          } 

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(CommentsFeedObj... params) {
            System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.SaveComment.doInBackground()");

            StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer("");
            List<NameValuePair> nameVauePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            InputStream is=null;

            CommentsFeedObj obj=params[0];
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ts_long", obj.getTs_long()+""));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("skid", obj.getSkid()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", obj.getUserName()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp", obj.getTimestamp()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userProfileImg", obj.getUserProfileImg()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userMsg", obj.getUserMsg()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("host_name", obj.getHost_name()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gallery_name", obj.getGallery_name()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("logonUserName", obj.getLogonUserName()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("logonUserMobileNumber", obj.getLogonUserMobileNumber()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("logonUserId", obj.getLogonUserId()));
            nameVauePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userLocation", obj.getUserLocation()));

            try {

              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Variable.WS_URL_SAVE_COMMENTS);
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameVauePairs));
              HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost);
              StatusLine statusLine= response1.getStatusLine();
              System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.SaveComment.doInBackground() | statusLine | "+statusLine);

              {
                  HttpEntity entity =response1.getEntity();
                  is=entity.getContent();
                  InputStreamReader in =new InputStreamReader(is);
                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                  String info="";
                  String nl=System.getProperty("line.separator");

                  while((info=br.readLine())!=null){
                      response.append(info.toString()+nl);
                  }

                  System.out.println("CommentPageActivity.SaveComment.doInBackground() | response.toString() | "+response.toString());
                  br.close();   
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }// doBackGroud
      }// SaveComment


/*  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_comment_page, menu);
        return true;
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        finish();
        return true;
    }

}

----------------- MyAdapter Class   
package com.sk.comment;


import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.sk.bhangarwaala.R;
import com.sk.faq.AppController;
import com.sk.variable.Variable;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {    
    private Context activity;
    //private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<CommentsFeedObj> feedItems;

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private static int counter;

    /*public MyAdapter(Activity activity, List<CommentsFeedObj> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }*/


    public MyAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<CommentsFeedObj> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activity = applicationContext;
        this.feedItems = data;
        //inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(feedItems!=null)
        return feedItems.size();

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CompleteListViewHolder viewHolder; 
        View v = convertView; 
        counter=counter+1;
        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             v = li.inflate(R.layout.comment_page_list_comments, null);
             viewHolder = new CompleteListViewHolder(v);  
             v.setTag(viewHolder);  
        }else{
             viewHolder = (CompleteListViewHolder) v.getTag();  
        }

        CommentsFeedObj item = feedItems.get(position);
        System.out.println("MyAdapter.getView() | item | "+item.toString());
        // sk id 
        viewHolder.commentPageTvSkid.setText(item.getSkid());
        viewHolder.commentPageTvSkid.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // user profile img
        if (item.getUserProfileImg()!=null && !item.getUserProfileImg().equalsIgnoreCase("null") && item.getUserProfileImg().length() >0){      // 1
            String img=item.getHost_name()+"/"+item.getGallery_name()+"/"+item.getUserProfileImg();
            System.out.println("MyAdapter.getView() | img | "+img);
            viewHolder.commentPageNivProfileImg.setImageUrl(img, imageLoader);
        }else{
            System.out.println("MyAdapter.getView() | DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMG | "+imageLoader);
            viewHolder.commentPageNivProfileImg.setImageUrl(Variable.DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMG, imageLoader);// 1
        }

        // user name
        viewHolder.commentPageTvUserName.setText(item.getUserName().toUpperCase());
        // time stamp
        viewHolder.commentPageTvTimestamp.setText(item.getTimestamp());
        // user msg
        if(item.getUserMsg()!=null){
            viewHolder.commentPageTvUserMsg.setText(item.getUserMsg()); 
        }else{
            viewHolder.commentPageTvUserMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return v;
    }
}//MainClass

class CompleteListViewHolder {  
    //http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/
    TextView commentPageTvUserName,commentPageTvTimestamp,commentPageTvUserMsg ,commentPageTvSkid  ;
    NetworkImageView commentPageNivProfileImg ;

    public CompleteListViewHolder(View convertView) {  
        commentPageTvUserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentPageListCommentsTvUserName);
        commentPageTvTimestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentPageListCommentsTvTimestamp);
        commentPageTvUserMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentPageListCommentsTvUserMsg);
        commentPageTvSkid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentPageListCommentsTvSkid);
        commentPageNivProfileImg = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentPageListCommentsNivProfileImg);

    }  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `on top`?

Comment: I have created ListView for displaying comments. When we add new commnents, i wish that should appears on top..

Comment: finally done, i have used this data.add(0,obj), thanks a lot dear for giving precious time and kind suggests.

Comment: Sahil, try to improve your question and not posting all code, leave only relevant code in the question. Thanx for the patience.

Answer (score 2):

When you add new commnent, always add this comment at the beginning of your `data`. Then refresh you `ListView`

```
data.add(0, commnent);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I have created ListView for displaying comments. When we add new commnents, i wish that should appears on top.

Comment: when you add a comment, use my code to add your comment to you `ListView`

Comment: I am using customer Adapter and there is no ADD option in it

Comment: what is the `data` in your code, it is the array or what?

Comment: I have created CommentObj Class, that holds Msg, UserName, ProfileImg and then pass this object to MyAdapter to populate ListView.

Comment: ok, please post your adapter code

Comment: I have edited question with Code for better understanding. You may have look and suggest.

Comment: You say *I am using customer Adapter and there is no ADD option in it*, but I see in your  code, the `data` is a `List` => of course it have a ADD options

Comment: checking your option and update in a few minutes

Comment: done, thanks a lot dear for giving precious time and kind suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can you this before init new Adapter:

```
data.add(0, value);
```

This will add new value in the begin of your list.

Comment: dear, i am using custom adaptor and there is no such option in it.

Comment: your custom adapter is extends BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter?

Comment: My Customer Adapter extends BaseAdapter

Comment: just use my way is OK. add it to your List before init the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Pl have a look of below code and advice
void loadCommentsView(){
  try {
   listAdapter= new MyAdapter(this, data);
   commentPageLvCommentsList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
   listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  } 
 }
void performAddCommentsOperation(){
  CommentsFeedObj obj = new CommentsFeedObj();
  obj.setUserMsg(msg);
  data.add(obj);
  listAdapter= new MyAdapter(this, data);
  listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

Comment: you can edit your question and paste that code in your question

Comment: I have also edited question with Code. You may have a look

Comment: @sahil  in `data.add(obj);` you can change it to `data.add(0, obj);`

Comment: seems good, checking and will let you know in minutes.

Comment: done, thanks a lot dear for giving precious time and kind suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Finally done, I have used this data.add(0,obj) instead of data.add(obj) on onClick Action.

```
void onClickCommentButton(){
        data.add(0,obj);
        listAdapter= new MyAdapter(this, data);
        commentPageLvCommentsList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just accept one of the answers that suggested that, instead of posting another one that basically says the same thing?

Comment: every time you click the button, you will new your adapter again.I think you are not really understand what adapter and listView do.

Comment: finally done, i have used this data.add(0,obj), thanks a lot dear for giving precious time and kind advice..

Answer (score -1):

You will be able to do by adding header at top. There should be methods with adapterView or list. I had done last year . It allows only one header item per list though I remember.